# jqGrid - Highlight current row in cell edit mode?

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid cell edit mode (`cellEdit: true`), is there a way to highlight not just the selected cell, but also the row the cell is on as well?

Answer (score 0):

Saw that the default functionality was for the row to be highlighted as well. Further investigation found that I was overriding the cell colors somewhere else in the code.